# XML Data type column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, database, ssms

I have a table called assessments. In that table, we are storing responses to a list of questions from the application and we have an XML column with an XML data type that stores the same responses for the questions in the XML format. Mostly the XML column will have a null value when the user is refused to pass it. Can anyone know how much storage it will take for the XML column if the values are passed and not passed?.

Comment: Care to share some sample data, the quantity of the fields in the XML data?
Have you tested?
Here's a google search tht might help.
https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=xml+data+size+sql+server

Answer (score 0):

The internal representation of an XML document is not what you see when looking at the XML document.

Here is a good link on the subject: [Where to find the size of SQL Server data types?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/147296/where-to-find-the-size-of-sql-server-data-types)

For example, contrary to popular belief, XML is smaller than JSON.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, jsondata NVARCHAR(MAX), xmldata XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (jsondata, xmldata)
VALUES
(N'{
    "SquidGame": {
        "Genre": "Thriller",
        "Rating": {
            "@Type": "Imdb",
            "#text": "8.1"
        },
        "Stars": [
            "Lee Jung-jae",
            "Park Hae-soo"
        ],
        "Budget": null
    }
}', N'<SquidGame>
      <Genre>Thriller</Genre>
      <Rating Type="Imdb">8.1</Rating>
      <Stars>Lee Jung-jae</Stars>
      <Stars>Park Hae-soo</Stars>
      <Budget />
    </SquidGame>');

SELECT * 
    , jsondata_length = DATALENGTH(jsondata), xmldata_length = DATALENGTH(xmldata)
FROM @tbl;
```

**Output**

```
+----+-----------------+----------------+
| ID | jsondata_length | xmldata_length |
+----+-----------------+----------------+
|  1 |             374 |            220 |
+----+-----------------+----------------+
```

Comment: FWIW - Interestingly the size of JSON is dependant on whitespace while XML is not.  Removing the whitespace from the JSON reduces the datalength, not so for XML where the datatype is clearly optimized.

Comment: Poor example, because the XML is minified on insertion, and the JSON isn't. Better to compare either both minified https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c75d81959b0c48af28239e9636065e44 where the difference is much less. Also I'm not entirely convinced `DATA_LENGTH` is accurate for `xml` anyway, I need to test. By the way, although SQL Server doesn't have it, Postgres has `jsonb` which is also compressed and the same size as `xml` when stored https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=05580420a71b35d4fdcdb4f4c79b58c9

Comment: Exactly the opposite. No popular mythology on the storage level.

Comment: Sorry didn't understand that, what does that mean?